# Levi Civita Epsilon-Kronecker Delta relation in four dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

I have been trying to work out the expression for $\varepsilon_{ijkl} \cdot \varepsilon_{ijkl}$. Setting up the determinants, I found that the answer was 6. But, I doubt that I am right. When I had $\varepsilon_{ij} \cdot \varepsilon_{ij}$, my answer was 2. For $\varepsilon_{ijk} \cdot \varepsilon_{ijk}$, my answer was 6, and I am a bit unconvinced that my process was right.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be $4!= 24$ as there are 24 possible $ijkl$'s with all indices distinct.

Comment: Do you have any hint on how to set up the determinants for this?

Comment: Determinants have nothing to do with it.  Each of the 24 terms in the sum is unity, so the sum is 24.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\varepsilon_{ijkl} \cdot \varepsilon_{mnpq}= \left|\begin{matrix}
\delta_{im}& \delta_{in}& \delta_{ip}& \delta_{iq} \\
\delta_{jm}& \delta_{jn}& \delta_{jp}& \delta_{jq} \\
\delta_{km}& \delta_{kn}& \delta_{kp}& \delta_{kq} \\
\delta_{lm}& \delta_{ln}& \delta_{lp}& \delta_{lq} 
\end{matrix}\right|
$$
Or for convincing you may use a brute force method, by starting with
$$
\varepsilon_{ijkl} =\delta^0_i\delta^1_j\delta^2_k\delta^3_l- \delta^0_i\delta^1_j\delta^2_l\delta^3_k + \delta^0_i\delta^1_l\delta^2_j\delta^3_k -
\delta^0_i\delta^1_l\delta^2_k\delta^3_j +
\delta^0_i\delta^1_k\delta^2_l\delta^3_j -
\delta^0_i\delta^1_k\delta^2_j\delta^3_l \\
-\delta^0_j\delta^1_i\delta^2_k\delta^3_l+ \delta^0_j\delta^1_i\delta^2_l\delta^3_k - \delta^0_j\delta^1_l\delta^2_i\delta^3_k +
\delta^0_j\delta^1_l\delta^2_k\delta^3_i -
\delta^0_j\delta^1_k\delta^2_l\delta^3_i +
\delta^0_j\delta^1_k\delta^2_i\delta^3_l \\
+\delta^0_k\delta^1_i\delta^2_j\delta^3_l- \delta^0_k\delta^1_i\delta^2_l\delta^3_j + \delta^0_k\delta^1_l\delta^2_i\delta^3_j -
\delta^0_k\delta^1_l\delta^2_j\delta^3_i +
\delta^0_k\delta^1_j\delta^2_l\delta^3_i -
\delta^0_k\delta^1_j\delta^2_i\delta^3_l \\
-\delta^0_l\delta^1_i\delta^2_j\delta^3_k+ \delta^0_l\delta^1_i\delta^2_k\delta^3_j - \delta^0_l\delta^1_k\delta^2_i\delta^3_j +
\delta^0_l\delta^1_k\delta^2_j\delta^3_i -
\delta^0_l\delta^1_j\delta^2_k\delta^3_i +
\delta^0_l\delta^1_j\delta^2_i\delta^3_k 
$$
You must see that$\varepsilon_{ijkl}\cdot \varepsilon_{ijkl} =24$

Comment: $\delta^3_k \delta^1_k= \delta^{31}=0$